# How to have Apex Trigger post Chatter field updates in one post?

Tags: apex, trigger, chatter

I currently have an apex trigger that posts to chatter for when a field is updated on a record. Currently, the trigger works but posts each update as a separate chatter message:

[image]

I want to have it where if someone makes multiple field updates in one edit, it posts to chatter like this:

[image]

^ two notes:
-burger and fries are two different fields on a test object called 'Menu' - I just used this as an example
-this is the default way that salesforce posts to chatter with chatter field tracking

If also possible, can I add to the trigger so that it posts to a specific group or user? The reason why I'm writing a trigger is that we need to track more than 20 fields on a record.

Here is my code:

```
  trigger AccountChatter on Account (after update) {
    List<Schema.FieldSetMember> lstTrackedFields = SObjectType.Account.FieldSets.AccountChatter.getFields();

    if (lstTrackedFields.isEmpty()) return;

    List<FeedItem> lstFieldChanges = new List<FeedItem>();

    if(!trigger.isUpdate) return;

    for (Account objNewAccount : trigger.new) {

        final Account oldAccount = trigger.oldmap.get(objNewAccount.Id);
        // Iterate over all fields in Fieldset
        for (Schema.FieldSetMember objField : lstTrackedFields) {
            String fieldName  = objField.getFieldPath();
            String fieldLabel = objField.getLabel();

            if (objNewAccount.get(fieldName) == oldAccount.get(fieldName))
                continue;

            String oldValue = String.valueOf(oldAccount.get(fieldName));
            String newValue = String.valueOf(objNewAccount.get(fieldName));

            if (oldValue != null && oldValue.length()>255)
                oldValue = oldValue.substring(0,255);

            if (newValue != null && newValue.length()>255)
                newValue = newValue.substring(0,255); 

            FeedItem post = new FeedItem();
            post.ParentId = objNewAccount.Id; // RecordId
            post.Body = UserInfo.getName()+' changed '+fieldLabel+' from '+oldValue +' to '+newValue ;

            lstFieldChanges.add(post);
        }
    }

    if (!lstFieldChanges.isEmpty()) insert lstFieldChanges;
```

Thank you all for reading, getting this to work will be a monumental help to our org and I will be forever grateful :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to have it where if someone makes multiple field updates in one edit, it posts to chatter like this:

This is actually a pretty simple change. See where you have

```
        FeedItem post = new FeedItem();
        post.ParentId = objNewAccount.Id; // RecordId
        post.Body = UserInfo.getName()+' changed '+fieldLabel+' from '+oldValue +' to '+newValue ;

        lstFieldChanges.add(post);
```

inside the inner `for` loop, which iterates field by field? You want that code to be in your *outer* `for` loop, that iterates Account by Account.

However, you're also wanting to accumulate a post body that mentions all of the changed fields. You can do that using very similar logic to what you're working with now. The way I like to do it is to accumulate a `List<String>`:

```
 List<String> changeDetails = new List<String>(); // at top of outer for loop
```

and then in my inner `for` loop

```
 changeDetails.add(fieldLabel+' from '+oldValue +' to '+newValue);
```

This allows you to efficiently template the final post body with `String.format()` when you're back at the bottom of your outer loop:

```
post.Body = String.format(
    '{} made the following changes:\n{}',
    new List<String> {
        UserInfo.getName(),
        String.join(changeDetails, '\n')
    }
);
```

> If also possible, can I add to the trigger so that it posts to a specific group or user? The reason why I'm writing a trigger is that we need to track more than 20 fields on a record.

Sure. Just change the `ParentId` of the feed item. You may want to amend the message to include details of the changed record. See the [FeedItem reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_feeditem.htm) under `ParentId`:

> ID of the object type to which the FeedItem object is related. For example, set this field to a UserId to post to someone’s profile feed, or an AccountId to post to a specific account.